# database primary key dynamoDB or other

Tags: node.js, database, amazon-dynamodb, alexa-skills-kit, querying

I am using DynamoDB for my Alexa skill. In the documentation for dynamoDB, it says that the primary key (and any secondary indexes) has to be one of three types: binary, string, number. I was wondering if there was a way to search the database using an array, or things like "tags" to try and match an item in the database with the most matching "tags" used to search the items. If this is not possible with dynamoDB, are there other databases that allow this functionality? Otherwise, what kind of service could I use (besides a database) that would allow me to do this kind of querying?

Answer (score 0):

DynamoDB has been designed for fast read/write and huge scaling. The best way to use dynamoDB is to dump a system of record data and then access whole object using some id. 
Some compromises have been made to deliver the speed. One of them is complex queries. For your use case, i think [ElasticSearch](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/es-gsg.html) is the best option.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So if I use ElasticSearch, how would the tags be used in the database? I mean isn't the primary key still going to have to be one of: string, binary, number?

Answer (score 0):

With DynamoDB you could achieve this by having your primary key composed of

- partition key (some unique id for each item), and
- sort key (the specific tag)

This leads to having duplicate data stored, since you'd need to store the item data for each of the tags in order to allow fast queries per keys.

The structure would be something like this

```
Partition (ID) | Sort (Tag) | other attributes
1234           | node.js    | { timestamp: "...", message: "...", ... }
1234           | database   | { timestamp: "...", message: "...", ... }
1234           | alexa      | { timestamp: "...", message: "...", ... }
```

Note that the partition key (ID) is same for each item, but the Sort key (Tag) changes. Other attributes can be anything you like, but in this case it is duplicated. Other items would be added in a similar manner with their unique id as partition key and tags as sort key, one per item.

This model is really optimized for fast reads. When a tag is deleted from an item, you'd delete the item accordingly.

But then some data in the item is changes, message attribute for example, you'd **need to change each item**, resulting in multiple writes. Also, the writes would not be atomic, resulting in some data possibly being stale.

Of course, it all depends on what other data query needs you application has and the amount of reads vs. writes you'll have, whether this would be valid approach or not.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So the thing is the sort key also is limited to String, Binary and Number. Let me try to be a bit more clear about what I'm asking. Let's say I have an item in the database and I want to tag it with more than one string so that I can search for it later on (I want to use these tags as keys). So let's say I have an item which represents a song, and I want to tag with "I like it", "favorite", "rock." etc... At the same time, each song has a different number of such tags, so I can't create "predefined" columns which categorize these tags for each item.

Comment: So now say I have a bunch of tags and I want to search the database for the item that has the most "matching" tags. How would I do this?

Comment: So you'll need to able to get items by giving only the tag. AFAIK in this you'd have to have the tag as partition key. You can have multiple indexes per table in Dynamo in order to support your queries. But then again, this would lead to (even more?) duplication. Unfortunately I cannot give you direct solution. Read [this detailed answer on Dynamo DB mappings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55152297/337120) and follow the links to external resources. And you could also consider that maybe DynamoDB is not the best too for the job, and perhaps a relational database would serve better. Good luck!